# Elastic Search different reults on URL query and JSON POST

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I'm completing a search function on a big online webstore.

I have a problem with additional fields. When I try searching for some fields in browser, it works, but when posting a JSON using bool filter, it gives me 0 results (doesn't raise an error).

Basically: when I visit localhost:9200/search/items/_search?pretty=true&q=field-7:Diesel
It works well, however, in JSON it doesn't.

I've been googling all day and couldn't find any help in ElasticSeach documents. What frustrates me even more is that some other fields in bool query work OK, but this one doesn't.

I don't have any mapping and ES works for me out of the box - querying on the "name" field works well, as well as any other field, as well as for this field too - but only inside browser.

I realise that querying ES over browser uses so called "query string query".

Anyway, here is an example JSON that I'm posting to ElasticSearch.
(searching all items that have "golf mk5" in their name, which have diesel fuel type - by searching field-7).

```
  {
        "query": {
            "filtered": {
                "filter": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must_not": [
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "sold": "1"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "user_id": "0"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "locked": "0"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "removed": "0"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "terms": {
                                    "field-7": [
                                        "Diesel"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "query": {
                    "match": {
                        "name": {
                            "operator": "and",
                            "query": "+golf +Mk5"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        "sort": [
            {
                "ordering": {
                    "price": "desc"
                }
            }
        ],
        "from": 0,
        "size": 24,
        "facets": {
            "category_count": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "category_id",
                    "size": 20,
                    "order": "count"
                }
            },
            "price": {
                "statistical": {
                    "field": "price"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a `query_string`-query, the text is analyzed. With the `term`-query (and -filter), it is not.

Since you're not specifying a mapping, you'll get the `standard`-analyzer for string fields. It tokenizes, lowercases and removes stopwords.

Thus, the term `Diesel` will be indexed as `diesel`. Your `terms`-filter is looking up the exact term `Diesel`, which is different.

Comment: So basically I should just adjust mapping so these fields are not_analyzed?

Comment: I've added a nested column called "fields", changed the mapping so it has index: not_analyzed. Now I'm unable to search by this nested field when querying with the same JSON CURL technique.

Comment: That's an entirely different question. :)

Comment: I'm sure you can help me with this one too :)